# How to have .profile sourced automatically

Tags: unix

I added to the path in ~/.profile and the path will be updated if I

```
source ~/.profile
```

but on system restart, ~/.profile is not loaded.  How can I make it automatic so I don't have to source it?  Is ~/.profile the right place to add to the path for something like grails bin?

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Bourne, Korn and Bash shells normally read `~/.profile`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not "on system restart" they don't.

Comment: I am using bash

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'on system restart', and the context in which the `~/.profile` is not being read.  Do you mean that it is not read by the shell in your terminal window?  Or something else?  Have you configured your terminal window to run a login shell?

Comment: "on system restart": when I restart my computer.  If I do echo $PATH in the terminal, the updates to the path are not there.  What is a login shell?  I don't think I have reconfigured my terminal window in that way.

Comment: for example, in bash. .bashrc normally source's ~/.profile Which means it gets read when you login.System restart wouldn't come into the matter. I think johnathan is trying to work out when exactly you expect this to work and it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke `bash` with either `-l` or `--login` to make it a login shell, one that looks for and reads `~/.profile`.  For more, refer to the `INVOCATION` section in `man bash`.

If there's something you want `bash` to run every time, not just when you make it a login shell, put that into `~/.bashrc`, not `~/.profile`.

If you're trying to decide what should go where, put stuff that can be inherited, e.g., environment variable settings into `~/.profile` and stuff that can't, like `alias` definitions into `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess as you do not state what OS you are running.

Assuming you are running a CDE desktop, make sure you have a line that reads

```
DTSOURCEPROFILE=true
```

at the end of your ~/.dtprofile